# Android: MapView does not react on touch events under some layers of WiFiSLAM

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am using the indoor positioning framework wifislam and have a programming question.
So far I have given a MapView by the indoorLocationView of WifiSLAM. I'm working with the following code.

```
    final IndoorLocationManager.Configuration config = new IndoorLocationManager.Configuration();
    indoorLocationManager = new IndoorLocationManager(this, config,
            onServiceConnected, LOCATION_CHOICE);
    indoorLocationView = indoorLocationManager.createLocationView(this,
            GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY);

    final View mapContainer = findViewById(R.id.mapcontainer);
    ((ViewGroup) mapContainer).addView(indoorLocationView.getView());
    MapView mapView = indoorLocationView.getGoogleMapView();
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pinred);
    itemizedOverlay = new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapView.getContext(), sm);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
```

and the AddItemizedOverlay has following methods:

```
@Override
public boolean onTap(GeoPoint geopoint, MapView mapView) {
    mapOverlays.clear();
    // geopoint = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int) event.getX(),
    // (int) event.getY());
    // latitude
    if (geopoint != null) {
        this.geopoint = geopoint;
        lat = geopoint.getLatitudeE6();
        // longitude
        lon = geopoint.getLongitudeE6();
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geopoint,
                "Task Position", "Derzeitige Position vom Task");
        this.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    }
    return false;
}
```

My problem is now, that the onTap method does not respond or react on touching on the device. As well the onTouch event has no reaction. I think those layers above of wifislam are preventing that I can reach the MapView. Is there any possibility to reach the MapView so I can add some markers on the map?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that there is a transparent view on top of the Google Maps view that is showing the floorplan.  Try adding a listener on the view returned by IndoorLocationView#getView, but that may screw up the pinch-zoom/panning controls; you should double-check the effect (you probably want to return false from your listener unless one of your markers has been tapped).

If that doesn't work, your best bet is to contact WiFiSLAM support with your use case so they can update their SDK to meet your needs.  Looks like there's a support email address in the FAQ topic of the help section of the SDK website.